# How to make Notepad++ take over from the standard notepad.exe

Tags: windows-xp, notepad++, notepad

I could do this easily with TextPad, then I got irritated with Textpad once I'd played with Notepad++.

Now that I've removed Textpad:

- I want Notepad++ to take over the right-click > Edit option in Explorer, and
- I want Notepad++ to come up when I type `notepad` in the command prompt.

I know that Notepad++ has a shell extension that allows one to do right-click > Edit in Notepad++. But my old right-click > Edit link remains, and I keep finding myself clicking on it, only to be rewarded with an error.

Comment: As an aside, to invoke a different editor from Internet Explorer: I'm not sure if this is still the case, but in older versions of Windows/IE putting a shortcut named Notepad (to whatever program you'd like to start) on your desktop would do the trick.

Comment: Some more info on "an error" might be helpful.

Comment: would you mind to let us know which OS you are referring to? you mentioned "c:\winnt", is it Windows NT 4.0 or 2000?

Comment: XP Pro 2002 SP2

Comment: see this website:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12617/how-to-replace-notepad-in-windows-7/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace Notepad in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/792/how-do-i-replace-notepad-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 8):

Notepad++ has an interface exactly for this. Go to

> Settings > Preferences > File > Association

From there you can choose what extensions you would like to associate with Notepad++, sorted into categories (with the option of adding custom ones)

Comment: ok so what about unknown file extensions? I want one option that works for everything, like textpad has

Comment: Unknown file extensions can be added via

`Settings > Prefrences > File Association > customize`

and type the custom file extension you want

Comment: It is worth noting that to make this work in windows 7, you must run notepad++ as an Administrator. Otherwise you can make these changes all day long, but it never works.

Comment: actually...still not getting the changes to stick around : (

Comment: I don't relish the prospect of going into notepad++ every time I encounter a new extension (some systems like to make their own)

Comment: Fiddling a bit with open with and these associations, I got it to work. Had to try several times though. (I used run as administrator.)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change the system files simply right click on a file and select "Open With > Choose Default Program".

Now just select Notepad++ and you're good to go.

The only drawback with this approach is that you need to do it for all file types you want to open with the new program (*.txt, *.log, *.xml or whatever), so if you have a lot of different text based files it's not the option for you.

Comment: yeah, the drawback kills this approach for me.

Comment: @Nick - no worries, I just thought I ought to mention it as a less drastic approach

Comment: The File Association settings don't stick (Window 7 64-bit), even when running Notepad++ as Administrator. However, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

[Replace Windows Notepad with more advanced editors](http://en.onsoftware.com/replace-windows-notepad-with-more-advanced-editors/)

Comment: that method probably worked in xp, probably won't in windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ has a shell extension that allows you to do `Right Click > Edit in Notepad++`

Comment: I know, but my old right click > edit link remains, and I keep finding myself clicking on it, only to be rewarded with an error!

Comment: Well, @Nick, that seems quite an important detail to me...

Answer (score 0):

i'm going to post michel's comment as an answer, because it looks like it should work. And it looks better than all the others. And i'll add another way myself, with the path.

The OP asked about the cmd prompt too.
[link from howtogeek about replacing the executable](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12617/how-to-replace-notepad-in-windows-7/)

Another way is open a cmd prompt,  type  `PATH=c:\dirwithbats;%PATH%`   or for permanence, edit the path variable in the dialog box.  Put a bat file  c:\dirwithbats\notepad.bat that launches your other editor.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool to automatically replace Notepad with Notepad++:

[Tool by FloatOverflow](http://floatoverflow.blogspot.com/2013/12/tool-to-replace-notepad-with-notepad.html)