# Replacing notepad.exe in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, notepad

OK, I *really really* want to replace the default notepad.exe in Windows 7 with Editpad (yes, I want to replace the actual executable, and no I don't want to use something like Notepad2, so please don't suggest that).  I used the following batch script which has worked for me before:

```
@echo off
TITLE EditPad Install Script for Complete Windows Vista and 7 Notepad Replacement
echo.
echo EditPad Install Script for Complete Windows Vista and 7 Notepad Replacement
echo Version 2.0
echo.
echo Confirm to apply? (Press Ctrl-C and answer Y to terminate)
pause
echo.
echo.

if exist %SystemRoot%\notepad.original.exe goto exist_editpad_already
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.original.exe goto exist_editpad_already
takeown /f %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe
takeown /f %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe
icacls %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe /grant "%USERNAME%":f
icacls %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe /grant "%USERNAME%":f
IF EXIST %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64 (bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions "DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS")
copy %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe %SystemRoot%\notepad.original.exe
copy %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.original.exe
echo.
echo Original notepad.exe has been renamed to "notepad.original.exe" in its original folder.
echo.
echo Overwriting %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe with "%~dp0\EditPad.exe"
copy "%~dp0\EditPad.exe" %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe /y
echo Overwriting %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe with "%~dp0\EditPad.exe"
copy "%~dp0\EditPad.exe" %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe /y
echo.
echo EditPad installation is completed.
echo If no error occurred, EditPad will now replace all Notepad functions.
echo.
pause
goto eof

:exist_editpad_already
echo.
echo INSTALLED EditPad ALREADY! (notepad.original.exe exists in windows or windows system32)
echo.
pause
goto eof

:eof
```

This script did replace notepad.exe with the Editpad executable, but now if I try and open a text file, I get the error "Your copy of NOTEPAD.EXE appears to have been damaged. Please try reinstalling it from the original setup package."

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.  What could I do to force Windows to let me use Editpad as my notepad.exe without giving me this stupid error message?

**UPDATE:**
I think I have some more information that may help things a bit.  The problem seems to be with me running editpad.exe *at all* inside the system32 directory.  If I substitute various other exe files for `system32\notepad.exe` they run fine, but when I try to run `editpad.exe` inside that directory, Windows 7 gives me a popup dialog: "The publisher could not be verified.  Are you sure you want to run this software?"  If I click Run, I get the 'file is damaged' error - but ONLY if I'm running it inside the system32 directory.  I need to find a way to get this exe running inside the system32 directory.

Comment: Why not just set the default program for .txt to editpad?

Comment: I knew someone was gonna say that.  Various things have notepad.exe's location hardcoded into them and it is just so much easier to replace notepad.exe than change file associations and config settings all over the place.

Comment: Good to know. [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/792/how-do-i-replace-notepad-in-windows-7) _might_ have some relevant information. I figured I'd try to contribute a little since I asked a question.

Comment: @jez - curious as to what "Various things" have notepad hard-coded into them?  I recommend following the instructions in the thread mentioned above and dealing with the "various things" as they come up.  Windows is trying very hard to not allow malware to replace a known good .exe with an unknown one. Messing with that is a bad idea in my mind

Comment: manual method here...http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12617/how-to-replace-notepad-in-windows-7/

Comment: @stolsvik I haven't had any answers that have worked for me yet.

Comment: Why not just ignore the error which tells you to reinstall from original setup package?

Comment: @ADTC The error is all that pops up - it stops the new notepad.exe from running at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace Notepad in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/792/how-do-i-replace-notepad-in-windows-7)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, the duplicate should be in the other direction.

Comment: @fixer1234 Why do you think that?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, compare the answers.  All of the upvoted answers but one are just links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My idea is to create a supporter app that can piggyback on the Image File Execution registry entries to run EditPad correctly.

**Note:** You will have to restore your **original** Windows Notepad first, either through the error message that pops up, or by undoing the changes you made. Otherwise Windows may keep pestering you with the error message no matter what you try.

**Tip:** [Notepad Replacer](http://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/) suggested by Dracs does something similar to what is below **automatically**. Try that first, unless you have reasons to avoid it such as the application being **closed source**. In which case, you can use the method below:

1. Create a batch file with the following code. The batch file could be named *Replacer.bat* for example, and it could be placed anywhere such as EditPad's installation folder. (I assume EditPad is installed in the path given. If not, please change it.)

   ```
   SET NotepadTempVar=%*
   IF DEFINED NotepadTempVar SET NotepadTempVar=%NotepadTempVar:"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"=%
   IF DEFINED NotepadTempVar SET NotepadTempVar=%NotepadTempVar:"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"=%
   IF DEFINED NotepadTempVar (
       FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ("%NotepadTempVar%") DO SET NotepadTempVar=%%A
   )
   IF DEFINED NotepadTempVar (
       START "" "C:\Program Files\EditPad\EditPad.exe" "%NotepadTempVar%"
   ) ELSE (
       START "" "C:\Program Files\EditPad\EditPad.exe"
   )
   ```

   - **CAUTION!** It is necessary to have the empty string `""` after START command, otherwise your system can go into an infinite loop of creating new *Command Prompt* windows.
   - You may have to verify the paths of the *original* Notepad in second and third lines to reflect your system. I found the paths to be same in both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. The paths are *case-insensitive* but be careful to keep the quote marks around them.
   - On 64-bit Windows, you may need to add this **extra** line between the second and third lines:

     ```
     IF DEFINED NotepadTempVar SET NotepadTempVar=%NotepadTempVar:"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe"=%
     ```
2. **(optional)** Use [Batch To Exe Converter](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Batch-To-Exe-Converter.shtml) to compile the batch file to an executable program. Choose the "Invisible application" option.

   - If you do not wish to use *Batch To Exe Converter*, you may use another solution, or you may use the batch file itself for the following steps, instead of the compiled `EXE` file. However, if you use the batch file itself, you will see a momentary flashing of a command window before EditPad opens.
3. Open *Registry Editor* by opening Start menu and searching for `regedit` (or using the Run command to run `regedit`).
4. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`
5. If a key (folder in left pane) named `notepad.exe` does not exist inside `Image File Execution Options`, click **Edit > New > Key** and type `notepad.exe` as the new key's name. If it already exists, simply navigate to it.
6. If an entry named `Debugger` (type REG_SZ) does not exist in the `notepad.exe` key (on right side), click **Edit > New > String Value** and type `Debugger` as the new entry's name.
7. Double-click the entry named `Debugger` and enter the full qualified location and name of the EXE file generated by *Batch To Exe Converter* **or** the batch file if you did not use a compiler. Enclose the location in quotation marks.

   - For example, assuming you have stored the batch file in EditPad's program folder, the value of Debugger entry could be `"C:\Program Files\EditPad\Replacer.bat"` **or** `"C:\Program Files\EditPad\Replacer.exe"` *where Replacer.bat is the batch file and Replacer.exe is the compiled EXE file obtained in step 2, if any*.
8. Test the setup by:

   - Opening Windows Notepad from Start Menu. EditPad should open instead.
   - Double-clicking on a text file or any file that's associated with Windows Notepad.
   - Testing other means you know should normally open Windows Notepad. They will very likely open EditPad instead.

If there are any problems, your paths in the batch file created in step 1 may not be correct. All other steps should be OK without any problem if you followed them correctly. Just verify and correct the paths in the batch file (and recompile EXE if needed).

Comment: This replacer batch file method works a treat.  Thanks!  But, could you tell me what you're doing with `NotepadTempVar`?  You seem to be defining it, and then keep checking whether it's defined...  Also, I advise removing your line about using 'Notepad Replacer'.  It's closed source and I don't like installing that on my system as I can't be sure what it does.  I will probably write something similar to that in future, but make it open source.

Comment: @Jez I'm using `NotepadTempVar` in the first `START` line. I mentioned 'Notepad Replacer' for others' sake (I did mention you can skip trying it if you have reasons to avoid it such as being "closed source".)

My batch file went through a LOT of changes and testing to come up with this current version. Initially I thought I could just throw in an `EditPad.exe "%2"` but it never worked. I came up with a much longer batch file to take care of the problem, but even that didn't work for some situations. Then slowly modifying and testing, I came up with this final version.

Comment: @Jez a little bit more about `NotepadTempVar`. It first takes the complete set of command line arguments. The second and third lines will remove the known paths of the system `notepad.exe` from `NotepadTempVar`. The reason why they (and other lines) have to check whether `NotepadTempVar` is defined is because if any of the `SET` operations receive an empty value to put in `NotepadTempVar`, it will become undefined, causing the next lines to work incorrectly (I have tested this already. Doing the removal of known path of `notepad.exe` on an undefined variable will give undesirable effects).

Comment: The last `IF DEFINED` ensures your EditPad doesn't behave incorrectly when the final value of `NotepadTempVar` is empty. (Notepad2 will _automatically_ open the **Open** dialog when an empty string `""` is passed in as the file name. I put in the check so that such things don't happen to anyone using my batch file, regardless of the replacement software they want to use.) This batch file also ensures paths with 2+ consecutive spaces don't break (my longer method failed). **PS:** I heard EditPad has an option to replace Notepad in its Config menu. Have you tried to find and use that first?

Comment: OK, but why would `NotepadTempVar` be undefined?  Doesn't the batch file always receive "notepad.exe fileToOpen"?  The only way I can think it would become undefined is if you're trying to open notepad.exe itself, in which case your code actually will break won't it?

Comment: The older version of Editpad I use doesn't have that option.  :-)  Besides I prefer this generic solution which doesn't rely on any one piece of software to have "replace Notepad" functionality.

Comment: @Jez I have ensured my batch file will **not** fail when `notepad.exe` is opened directly (through Start Menu shortcut, or even by going into `Windows/System32` directory and double-clicking on it). That was one of the tests I did. The `IF DEFINED` checks are actually for that, and to safeguard the batch file against any possible instance of an undefined `NotepadTempVar`. So that the proper commands are executed when the `NotepadTempVar` variables gets undefined (due to empty value being set to it using `SET` command). Hope it's clear :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Image File Execution Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/greggm/inside-image-file-execution-options-debugging) registry key.

- Open `regedit.exe` as Administrator.
- Navigate to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`
- Create a new key (folder) named `notepad.exe`
- Create a new `REG_SZ` value named `Debugger` and set its value to your path to the `Editpad.exe` executable.

Done.  This doesn't require modifying or removing the system's `notepad.exe`, but no matter how a program attempts to run it (just try double clicking the program from Explorer yourself), it will run EditPad.

If you're on 64-bit Windows and attempting to use a 32-bit program, make your changes in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\ CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` instead.  (This info found on the [Notepad2 - Replacing Windows Notepad](https://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/notepad2-Replacement.html) page.)

Comment: Well, that does change things, but instead it now gives me a different error.  :-)  "The data area passed to a system call is too small."

Comment: Check my edit.  If EditPad is a 32-bit app, you might need to make the changes in a different registry key.  Also of note, you can pass command line parameters as well if desired.

Comment: Putting it in the registry inside that `Wow6432Node` path still doesn't work.  :-(  I still get the same error.

Comment: I can only think of 2 things: 1. If your path to EditPad contains spaces (e.g., "Program Files"), is the full path to the executable quoted in the registry?  2. There's some sort of subtle bug in EditPad.  However, I just tested the demo of EditPad Pro in an XP VM and it worked for me.  (Given, that's 32-bit XP vs. 64-bit 7, but 32-bit `Notepad2.exe` works on my 64-bit Win 7 system as well as the 64-bit `Notepad2.exe` does for the same purpose.)

Comment: afrazier's answer is how Notepad2 *officially* "replaces" Notepad with itself during installation, without actually replacing the Notepad executable file `notepad.exe`. **However,** Notepad2 has a `/z` command line argument which avoids opening the original Notepad's executable file (`notepad.exe`) **as editable text** in Notepad2 (since the Windows' Debugger system will pass it to Notepad2). Unless EditPad has some similar argument that can make it ignore the passed in `notepad.exe` you won't be able to correctly use afrazier's answer.

Comment: @ADTC: Thanks for the explanation.  An interposing tool would be needed then to "eat" the first argument before opening the real text editor.  Looks like the Notepad Replacer tool Dracs' answer does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this on my computer using [Notepad Replacer](http://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/). It doesn't actually replace any files, but it does cause anything notepad would have done to use whatever program you choose. I haven't seen the original notepad since I installed it. The uninstall will also revert everything back easily.

Comment: @Jez This should actually work and also take care of the problem I mentioned in my previous long comment. Let me know if it doesn't, coz I have another idea for you to try.

Comment: @ADTC Please post your other idea as an answer.

Comment: Hmm ok @Jez. Btw, I hope you restored the original Windows Notepad (through the error message or by undoing your batch file change) before trying the *Notepad Replacer* here. If not, Windows is going to keep pestering you even if you try *Notepad Replacer*.

Comment: +1 - Good find that should allow Notepad to be replaced with any editor!

Comment: I don't like the look of Notepad Replacer because it's not open source and it doesn't tell you how it replaces Notepad.

Comment: @Jez Well then, hold on I'm preparing the answer (had to go away for a while).

Comment: @Jez it's done. I had to test a lot to get the batch file to work correctly in all situations, which is why I took so long to prepare the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you also need to replace the notepad.exe file in `%WINDIR%\winsxs\Backup` but even this might not work properly - this has to do with [Windows Resource Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382503%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the batch file in the administrator mode.

1. Right click on the batch file
2. Select "Run as administrator"
3. Proceed with the installation

If you have already executed this script before than most probably it won't work immediately and you will need to delete notepad.original.exe from %SystemRoot% and %SystemRoot%\System32:

```
rm %SystemRoot%\notepad.original.exe
rm %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.original.exe
```

Remember that you also need to run this in the administrator mode, so copy above lines into a file and proceed with the same instructions as for the original batch file above.

Comment: I did run it in administrator mode.  How would deleting the .original files help?

Comment: I have first tried it in non-admin mode and it has failed, but created .original files. Later when running in the admin mode it didn't work since .original files already existed. But as soon as I have deleted them - the script worked. I do not know why it doesn't work for you - I am also using Win7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> This script did replace notepad.exe with the Editpad executable, but
>   now if I try and open a text file, I get the error "Your copy of
>   NOTEPAD.EXE appears to have been damaged. Please try reinstalling it
>   from the original setup package."

*notepad.exe* is a *Windows protected file* that's why it's a bit tricky to replace it...

Here's a *manual* solution from the *HowTo Geek* web site: **How To Replace Notepad in Windows 7**

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12617/how-to-replace-notepad-in-windows-7/

Another option may be to use the Sysinternals command line utility *PsExec* in your batchfile with the following switches

```
...PsExec.exe" -i -d -s...
```

PsExec: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Hope this help. Let us know.

Comment: With regard to the HowTo Geek website, unfortunately Windows 7 idiotically refuses to run executables in the system32 directory for which "the publisher could not be verified", which seems to apply for my editpad.exe.  If I try to run it in the system32 directory, I get the "Your copy of NOTEPAD.EXE appears to have been damaged..." error.

Comment: Check this article: Windows: Disable “Publisher Could Not Be Verified” Messages  http://www.technipages.com/disable-publisher-could-not-be-verified-messages.html  Is it a solution for you? I hope so!  :)

Comment: @Jez Btw somebody commented on that HowToGeek article that *"I’ve been using EditPad for years now, and it can be set to replace Windows Notepad with no hassle – just by checking an option in its config menu."* Did you check for such an option in its config menu?