# Launch original notepad.exe when Notepad Replacer is installed

Tags: windows, notepad

I use [Notepad Replacer](https://superuser.com/a/214173/82470). I love [Notepad Replacer](https://superuser.com/a/214173/82470).

However, I want to test something with the original Notepad, but can't open it at all anymore. Not by executing `notepad` from cmd or powershell, nor by browsing to `C:\Windows\notepad.exe` and double clicking it.

How can I fire up original Notepad once, without uninstalling Notepad Replacer?

I have version 1.1.6.0 of Notepad Replacer, on a fully updated Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad.exe resides in C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe - have you tried there?

I don't have the software, but it claims not to alter any system files so the binary should still be available.

Comment: Hey, I _also_ have `notepad.exe` there, indeed. However, double-clicking it will still fire Notepad++ via Notepad Replacer, afraid your solution doesn't work. (Have you tried it yourself / did it work for you?)